# Convert datetime-local to UTC time in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

I have a form that a user can input a datetime

```
<input class="form-control" name="aution_end_time" required type="datetime-local id="auction_end_time-input">
```

Now what I would like to do is convert this "local datetime object" to UTC time and store that value in a hidden input of the form.

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="auction_end_time_utc">
```

How would I go about this?
To summarize:
user enters a datetime in the form, then once they do that the hidden input gets updated with the same datetime but in UTC. I am unsure of how to determine the users local time zone and how to convert to UTC. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for that.

See my code snippet! I changed `type="hidden"` to `type="text"` and `name` to `id` for the second input for presentational purpose.

```js
document.getElementById("auction_end_time-input").oninput = function() {
  var datetimeLocal = document.getElementById("auction_end_time-input").value;
  var datetimeUTC = moment.utc(datetimeLocal).format();
  document.getElementById("auction_end_time_utc").value = datetimeUTC;
}
```

```html
<!-- moment.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control" name="aution_end_time" required type="datetime-local" id="auction_end_time-input">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="auction_end_time_utc">
```

Comment: Hey @Rtrader, if you like an answer, you can also upvote - just in case you didn't know.

Comment: `moment.js` is a huge library (300KB+) - it's entirely unnecessary for doing local timezone conversions : JS's built-in `Date` type already performs Local Computer Time to/from UTC conversions for free, and you can get the user's timezone info from `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()` and `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`.

Answer (score 1):

Or one line of javascript:

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementByName('aution_end_time');

const isoDatetimeStr = (new Date(inputEl.value)).toISOString();
```